# I need a tool to automatically do a Google Translate operation on all tweets in my Twitter feed

Tags: twitter, google-translate

I've been using [TweetDeck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TweetDeck) to translate foreign language tweets, but TweetDeck requires two clicks per tweet to call [Google Translate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate) and translate the tweet. Do any Twitter clients, web based or otherwise, have this feature?

Comment: Oh, man, maybe after all I can try and write you one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[10+ Tools to Translate Tweets in Twitter Automatically](http://www.aboutonlinetips.com/twitter-translation-tools/)* lists a whole bunch of ways to do this.

Comment: The website you linked to is a UX dumpster fire and the original content is no longer present. In the future, write a synopsis or excerpt the information into the post; don't promote link rot within StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

Something you could try is to go to http://translate.google.com and put in the URL to your Twitter page, telling it detect the language. I admittedly, though, am not sure if it will do multiple languages from a single page...

Comment: I tried.  It detects one language per page and twitter wants authorizaton to view the following list, so entering the URL wasn't working. The google chrome addin seems to have the same problem - ie. it can only detect 1 language per page.

Comment: @matthew: yeah, was trying to get to go also but no dice. I thought that I had gotten it to detect a language in the middle of a different language at one point. I can't get it to go now either. Sorry!

Comment: Have you tried the individual tweet ?

Comment: @phwd: he didn't want it tweet-by-tweet

Answer (score 1):

Use the Google Translate API. An example is in *[how to detect source language](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#AutoTranslate)*.
Good luck!

Comment: The link now says "Deprecated". On 2011-05-26, Google announced that the Google Translate API had been deprecated and that it would cease functioning on 2011-12-01.

Answer (score 1):

The twitter search web interface has this functionality already:

[Translate http://cl.ly/1nr4/content](http://cl.ly/1nr4/content)

Clicking this translates all tweets on the page to english, or presumably whatever language you have set in your preferences:

[Translated http://cl.ly/1nqe/content](http://cl.ly/1nqe/content)

It doesn't seem to be be implemented anywhere else on twitter though, which is a shame, and I can't find any way of getting your timeline as a search query to use this. I do hope this is rolled out everywhere at some point

Comment: Malicious file warning.